# The remote server returned error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, proxy-authentication, http-status-code-407

I use this code with .NET 3.5 and receive error "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    try
    {
        string webPageStr = client.DownloadString(URL);
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FAIL");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However, this code works smoothly with .NET 4.0 as this line is sufficient to pass the proxy authentication while it is not for .NET 3.5.

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Therefore, I tried many other ways to solve this problem but none of them works:

1) Replace CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials line with

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);
```

2) Create new proxy object

```
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, port);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass, domain);
client.Proxy = proxy;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass, domain);
```

3) Add this line

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

4) Use HttpWebRequest instead of WebClient and repeat every procedure above. This is sample code.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass, domain);
webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass, domain);

try
{
    webRequest.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("FAIL");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I feel like I come to a dead end as I have to use .NET 3.5. There must be difference between these two .NET versions that I do not know. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Ever find a 3.5 solution? I'm running into same thing, 4.0 update looks like only option.

Answer (score 11):

Just add this to config

```xml
 <system.net>
      <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
      </defaultProxy>
   </system.net>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue with Visual Studio solutions before. This helped me:

Open IE. Go to Tools -> Internet Options. Click on the Connections tab, then the LAN Settings button. Uncheck the "Automatically detect settings".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes restarting Visual Studio resolves this issue.