# VS 2013 The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, proxy

First, I tried everything in
[The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581609/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-407-proxy-authentication-required)
[The remote server returned error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590426/the-remote-server-returned-error-407-proxy-authentication-required)
and similar pages, but to no avail - changed App.config, devenv.exe.config and mtm.exe.config. Proxy settings are in IE. 
I get this error during build trying to build microsoft prism StockTraderRI_Desktop example. MS Server 2012 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

After serveral days struggle, I accidentally clicked Output tab (instead of Error List), where I saw that message was from Nuget trying to do stuff during build time. So I googled Nuget 407 and tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/36404624/3423333
And it worked finally. Not sure if my previous manipulations has any effects with this.